# angular2 custom modal component iframe issue

Tags: angular, iframe, modal-dialog

- I have written custom modal component in angular2. In the modal I am opening third party html as iframe. I will have 1 or 2 buttons to open the modal(internally iframe). Facing issue only when I have 2 buttons.
- On 1st button click iframe launching without any issue. Onclick of 2nd button third party url link **getting called twice & its failing**.
- Because of security reasons 2nd invocation to 3rd party html is not    allowed, as the request is going 2nd time in my case it is failing to    load content.
- Sometimes even if the iframe link gets called single time still it is failing. So not getting what is the actual issue.
- As per analysis this maybe due to cache issue. How to stop caching in iframe. Or any advice is welcome.

Having below code in modal

```
<iframe [src]="third/party/url.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: add more code to the post to help you

Comment: Possibly browser dependent. Some browsers cache the iframes some don't. If possible you can retrieve the contents of the third party url on the server side and serve from your app's domain.

Answer (score 2):

in angular2+ you have to do check this for security reasons,

in html

```
 <iframe class="e2e-iframe-untrusted-src" [src]="url"></iframe>
```

and in .ts file in

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

url=this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(res.data.url);
```

Answer (score 0):

For **RC.6^** version use **DomSanitizer**

And a good option is using pure pipe for that:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
} 

@NgModule({
   declarations : [
     ...
     SafePipe
   ],
})
```

html

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" [src]="url | safe"></iframe>
```

For **RC.5**

You can leverage `DomSanitizationService` like this:

```
export class YourComponent {
  url: SafeResourceUrl;
  constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizationService) {
    this.url = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('your url');
  }
}
```

And then bind to `url` in your template:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" [src]="url"></iframe>
```

Don't forget to add the following imports:

```
import { SafeResourceUrl, DomSanitizationService } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Comment: Tried this, but no luck.. Is there anyway to stop caching completely for the whole application [including iframe content]?